# Lightswitch data from Web API as data source

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-lightswitch, 3-tier, lightswitch-2013

I am trying to build a lighswitch 3-tier application that uses a data from a Web API.

Do you have sample resources/examples/advices how to set a data source from a web api?
It is easy to find samples when the data in the Data tier is comming from a database but I am having a problem when the Data tier is from Web API.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If the Web Api exposes web services that are oData conform then you can define a new oData Datasource in your Lightswitch Application and connect directly.
If this is not the case then you must implement a RIA Service that connects to the Web Api, the result of this process is a dll. After that  you are able to define a new RIA Service Datasource in your Lightswitch application connecting to the mentioned dll.